# Switching arguments in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this little Prolog program. It multiplies two numbers only doing addition.

```
mult(0, _, 0).
mult(1, X, X).
mult(X, Y, R) :- X > 1, X1 is X - 1, mult(X1, Y, R1), R is Y+R1.
```

Now I thought of optimizing this by reordering the arguments, so that X is always the smaller of the two arguments and therefore doing less recursion, so I added this line:

```
mult(X, Y, R) :- X > Y, mult(Y, X, R).
```

This does not work and I don't really understand why. For example `mult(3, 0, 0).` answers with *four* times `true` and then `false`. I obviously just want to have it return `true` once and then `false` afterwards. There are also combinations which work fine like `mult(0, 3, 0).`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but yields redundant solutions.
The problem is that you have a single base case `mult(0,_,0).` that only check for the first argument to be 0, and not a base case that would give 0 whenever any of the first two arguments is 0. Also your second base case is really not needed.

When you add your "interchange arguments" clause you open the possibility of either interchange it when X > Y or just continue with the next clause, and that is why you end up with multiple solutions when the second argument was 0.

For example, the query `mult(3,0, M).` can either succeed by first exchanging 3 with 0, then calling `mult(0,3, M).` will succeed with M=0, o continue with the next clause that subtracts 1 to X and calls `mult(2,0, M1).` which again can yield a solution by first exchanging arguments or falling through the next clause until the first argument is 1 which guards against proceeding with the last clause.

You may fix it by renaming your procedure to something else and adding a wrapper which calls your procedure with the argument order of your like. e.g.:

```
mult(X, Y, R):-
  X > Y -> mult1(Y, X, R) ; mult1(X, Y, R).

mult1(0, _, 0).
mult1(1, X, X).
mult1(X, Y, R) :- X > 1, X1 is X - 1, mult1(X1, Y, R1), R is Y+R1.
```